# To remove the left and right background colors for rounded breadcrumbs

Tags: css, rounded-corners, breadcrumbs

I set rounded breadcrumbs for navigation. How can I remove the left and right backgrounds as seen in the following image.

[image]

```css
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}
.tabs a {
  color: #363c46;
  float: left;
  width: 135px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs a.active {
  background: #fefb09;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.tabs a:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
.tabs a:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  background: #d1d1d1;
  /* to render the right end look */
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <a class="active">Item 1</a>
  <a>Item 2</a>
  <a>Item 3</a>
  <a>Item 4</a>
  <a>Item 5 </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Use...pseudo elements first child and last child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br6463pd/1/)

```
.tabs {
overflow: hidden;
background: #eee;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add border radius to the tab.

```css
.tabs {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I was too focused on the a tags. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired `border-radius` to the parent element and remove it from the child elements.

In your `.active` class change the `border-radius` value to `inherit` to have the same value of the property declared in its parent element. If you decide to change the parent's `border-radius` this will save you from having to change it in the `.active` class as well.

```css
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block; /* Needed to display inline but retaining its block characteristics */
}
.tabs a {
  color: #363c46;
  float: left;
  width: 100px; /* Changed for illustration purposes */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs a.active {
  background: #fefb09;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
.tabs a:last-child {
  background: #d1d1d1;
  /* to render the right end look */
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <a class="active">Item 1</a>
  <a>Item 2</a>
  <a>Item 3</a>
  <a>Item 4</a>
  <a>Item 5 </a> 
</div>
```